# Java regex pattern to exculde some group strings

Tags: java, regex

I have a regular expression such as `^([1-9]\\d*)([dDmMwWyY])$`

It matches like 1d,10d,2W,100Y etc.

Now I want to match 0d,0D along with above but not 0w,0y,0m.

So how should I write my regular expression?

If I write `^([0-9]\\d*)([dDmMwWyY])$`
This will matches 0w which is not I want

And I want the digits in macher.group(1) and string in group(2)

Comment: Java is not Javascript, nor does this question have anything to do with jQuery. Please make an effort to figure out the language you want to write code in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well, something like that:

```
^([0-9]+[dD]|[1-9]\d*[mMwWyY])$
```

This would match any number suffixed by d or D, and only number starting with '1' for the remaining. You may also write this and use either `(?i)`, either `Pattern.IGNORE_CASE` as option:

```
^([0-9]+d|[1-9]\d*[mwy])$
```

If you want match(0) and match (1) as explained in your comment:

```
^([0-9]+(?=[dD])|[1-9]\d*)([dmwyDMWY])$
```

The positive look-ahead assertion will work only with d/D as intended, thus it catpure `0d` but not `0y`.

Comment: I want the digits and string separate

Comment: You know that you may use Java after matching a pattern. You may also use a simplier substring() because you know, in that context, that the last char is always a specifier while the other are always digit. Still, I'll try to work you that regexp.

Answer (score 0):

why not just

```
 ^(0d)$|^([1-9]\\d*)([dDmMwWyY])$
```

it's unambiguous. you want either 0d, or the rest of the work hours.